# Smooth element translate on device orientation change

Tags: javascript, css, orientation

I'm trying to achieve [this sort of effect](http://admin.sparkflow.net/d/site.html?params=%7B%22id%22%3A473%2C%22file%22%3A%22%5B%7B%5C%22src%5C%22%3A%5C%22%2F%2Fsparkflow-a.akamaihd.net%2Fspk%2F13%2F473-1426085900%2Fm0-0.html%5C%22%2C%5C%22width%5C%22%3A%5C%229%5C%22%2C%5C%22height%5C%22%3A%5C%229%5C%22%2C%5C%22name%5C%22%3A%5C%22Main%5C%22%7D%5D%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Rio%202%22%2C%22size%22%3A467241%2C%22token%22%3A%221434437578%3AeyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjE0MzQ0Mzc1Nzh9.svs67X2h2qqnI_FEOhgDEzkpaUlERYdJT-qnty9NIiE%22%2C%22format%22%3A11%2C%22device%22%3A%222%22%7D&d=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6IjQ3MyIsImZvcm1hdCI6IjExIn0.qGE62-nK9sJX8rAzli-jBeP94Zfb32XmDLhE6GeSgAc&device=Apple%20iPhone%205%20%2F%205S%20%2F%205C&zoom=1.55), but by using JS and on device orientation change (with gyroscope). So I wrote this code:

```
var sky, flag, objects, maxPositiveTranslateFar = 30, maxPositiveTranslateNear = 20, maxNegativeTranslateFar=-30, maxNegativeTranslateNear=-20;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",onload); 
function onload(){
    sky = document.getElementById('sky');
    flag = document.getElementById('flag');
    objects = [{objectName : sky}, {objectName : flag}];

    if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
        window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(eventData){
            var tiltLR = eventData.gamma;
            var tiltD = eventData.beta;
            deviceOrientationHandler(tiltLR, tiltD);
        }, false);
    } else {
        // Do something
    }
}

function deviceOrientationHandler(tiltLR, tiltD) {
    for(var i = 0; i <= objects.length - 1; i++){
        if(objects[i].objectName == flag){
            if(tiltLR > maxPositiveTranslateNear){
                tiltLR = maxPositiveTranslateNear;
            } else if(tiltLR < maxNegativeTranslateNear) {
                tiltLR = maxNegativeTranslateNear;
            }
            flag.style.webkitTransform = "translateX("+tiltLR+"px)";
        } else {
            if(tiltLR*1.7 > maxPositiveTranslateFar){
                tiltLR = maxPositiveTranslateFar;
            } else if(tiltLR*1.7 < maxNegativeTranslateFar) {
                tiltLR = maxNegativeTranslateFar;
            }
            if(tiltD > maxPositiveTranslateNear){
                tiltD = maxPositiveTranslateNear;
            } else if(tiltD < maxNegativeTranslateNear) {
                tiltD = maxNegativeTranslateNear;
            }
            sky.style.webkitTransform = "translateX("+(tiltLR*1.7)+"px) translateY("+tiltD+"px)";
        }
    }
}
```

It works, the sky and flag elements are moving correspondingly, however the movement isn't smooth as in the example above. I guess it's because the values are constantly changing when the device is rotated, thus the `deviceorientation`event keeps firing. I tried to add `transition` to these elements' CSS:

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-out;
```

But it just made things worse - the transform became really jumpy.

Does anybody have a solution how to make this transformation smooth? I have to do it with plain JS/CSS only, no external JS libraries (or by using a library, but it must very light-weight, 40-50 kb. is the max).

Comment: You mean Parallax effect?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Well, yeah, sort of. Just as in example I mentioned.

Comment: Nice man... Let's see if someone is answering. I am not so good in CSS Transforms. All the best!